# Python substring checking not working as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple web scraper in Python, here is the code (so far)

```
import requests, pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
music = []
page = requests.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
allTags = soup.find_all('a')
for tag in allTags:
    toCheck = "www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/"
    if toCheck in tag:
        music.append([tag.get("href"),tag.contents])
    pprint.pprint(music)
```

When running the following commands in the Python shell (with example inputs):

```
>>> tag = "<a href=\"//www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/11853\">-sunrise-</a>"
>>> toCheck = "www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/"
>>> toCheck in tag
True
```

It returns True. But the if statement in the program is never running, even though those example inputs should pass it at some point, as well as other valid inputs. I have used various print statements to verify this.

EDIT - Solved

Replace

```
if toCheck in tag:
```

With

```
if toCheck in str(tag):
```

Comment: What's `page_url`?

Comment: page_url = "https://waterflame.newgrounds.com/audio/"
Sorry, forgot to add

Comment: what does find_all return? is it a list of strings or a list of Tag objects?

Comment: Checking tag.__class__ shows that they are bs4 tag objects. Thanks for noticing!